# In python __init__ dictionary arguments defaulting to previous class values

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-2.7, instance-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I'm finding that dictionary arguments to the **init**() function of my class are defaulting to values I've previously set in previous instances. I really don't understand this behavior, and it doesn't seem to happen with lists or basic variables. Example code:

```
class TestClass:
  def __init__(
    self,
    adir={},
    alist=[],
    avar=None
  ):
    print("input adir: " + str(adir)) #for test2, shows test1.mydir
    self.mydir = adir
    self.mylist = alist
    self.myvar = avar

test1 = TestClass()   
test1.mydir['a'] = 'A'
test1.mylist = ['foo'] 
test1.myvar = 5

test2 = TestClass()
print(test2.mydir) #has same value of test1!
print(test2.mylist)
print(test2.myvar)
```

The output looks like this:
    initializing test1
    input adir: {}
    initializing test2
    input adir: {'a': 'A'}
    {'a': 'A'}
    []
    None
Why does the dictionary argument (adir) to test2 get set to test1.mydir? Especially, why is the behaviour different than other mutable types like list?

Thank you!

Comment: The only reason that `mydir` behaves differently than `mylist` is that you set an *element* of `test1.mydir` but you replace `test1.mylist`.  Otherwise this is the mutable default argument issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DSM says, don't modify mutable default arguments.  Do this instead:

```
class TestClass:

  def __init__(self, adir=None, alist=None, avar=None):
    if alist is None:
      alist = []
    if adir is None:
      adir = {}
```

Comment: +infinity. (*ahem* - almost) Always use `None` for defaults

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never realized this problem before... Now that I know the problem, I did a bit of googling. For posterity,  [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) isn't a bad discussion of what's going on here.

Comment: and same issue for instance variable... use self.alist = {} is alist is None else alist